# Delete a field value based on checkbox-Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I have a requirement where if the user unchecks the checkbox the vale of certain field should be cleared while he saves it.

To be printed is a checkbox
Check # is field.

If the user unchecks the "To be Printed" checkbox the check # field should be clear while he saves the page.

This should be a user event and will be it be after submit funtion?
How do i achieve this?

Comment: My immediate thought was that this should be a Client script using the fieldChanged event, any reason why this needs to be a User Event script?

Comment: The user is going to check/uncheck the check box through UI so i wrote a code like `if (bToBePrinted == 'F')`
              ` {`
               ` recBillPayment.setFieldValue('tranid', null);`
                `}`

Comment: Now the Check # is automatically generated in sequence. My requirement is 1) If the user edits the check # and saves it should save with the value entered by the user . 2) The old sequence should follow on for the next payments.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have two options to deal with your requirement.

1) You can write a Client script as @John mentioned above on his comment and  on field change you can clear out those field values which you don't want to save upon your form submission.

2) Write a before submit function and validate the checkbox field value, if it is unchecked then clear out those fields, which you don't want to save.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `user event before submit` script to set field value as null, as client script may not fire if data entry point is through csv import, suitescript, etc.

```
if (nlapiGetFieldValue(TO_BE_SUBMITTED_FIELD_ID) == 'F'){
  nlapiSetFieldValue('tranid', null);` 
}
```

If you wish, You may write additional client script to disable/clear the field if value of checkbox is set to false, for better UX.

For sequence number I would say, use the below code (I am assuming sequence numbers are pure numbers)

```
if (nlapiGetFieldValue(TO_BE_SUBMITTED_FIELD_ID) == 'T'){
//search in descending order (use this code in your same before submit script)   
var search = nlapiCreateSearch(RECORD_TYPE, ['mainline', 'is', 'T'], new nlobjSearchColumn('tranid').setSort(true));
var results = search.runSearch();
var records = results.getResults(0, 1);

var nextTranId = praseInt(records[0].getFieldValue('tranid'), 10) + 1;
nlapiSetFieldValue(tranid, nextTranId);
}
```